# Copying executables (x86 or x64) to remote machines based on windows system type (x86 or x64)

Tags: batch-file

I need help to achieve the following through a batch file. Here's what I'm trying to do,

1. Run psexec to execute "systeminfo" and find the string "System Type"
2. Determine the "System Type" (whether "X86-based PC" or "X64-based PC") from the PsExec output.
3. Map the drive locally on my PC and copy the file based on the system type.

Here's my script!

```
@echo off
set logs="C:\logs.txt"

for /f %%i in (C:\pro_arch.txt) do (

    echo %%i >> %logs%
    PsExec.exe \\%%i -u domain\username -p "password" systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Type" >> "%Logs%"

        if "%%i"=="System Type:               X86-based PC" (
        net use m: \\%%i\C$ /user:domain\username "password"
        xcopy "C:\batch_file\x86.txt" \\%%i\C$\_support\setup\ /y
        net use m: /delete
        ) else (
        net use m: \\%%i\C$ /user:domain\username "password"
        xcopy "C:\batch_file\x64.txt" \\%%i\C$\_support\setup\ /y
        net use m: /delete
        )
)
```

The script works well untill this part

```
@echo off
set logs="C:\logs.txt"

for /f %%i in (C:\pro_arch.txt) do (

    echo %%i >> %logs%
    PsExec.exe \\%%i -u domain\username -p "password" systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Type" >> "%Logs%"
```

and outputs the following based on the system type:

System Type:               X86-based PC
or
System Type:               X64-based PC

The problem comes when the IF statement executes. It only copies the x64.txt to remote machines irrespective of the system type of the remote machine.

Command substitution using the psexec output doesn't work either,

`for /f "tokens=*" %%a in '(PsExec.exe \\IPaddress -u domain\username -p "password" systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Type")' do set myvar=%%a`

it says

`| was unexpected at this time`

Could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%%i contains the computer name, not the results of your PsExec, so of course your IF statement will never be true.

You must either quote or escape special characters like `|` when used in a FOR /F DO() clause. I recommend escaping as `^|`

```
@echo off
set logs="C:\logs.txt"

for /f %%i in (C:\pro_arch.txt) do (
  echo %%i >> %logs%
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('PsExec.exe \\%%i -u domain\username -p "password" systeminfo ^| findstr /c:"System Type"') do (
    >> "%Logs%" echo %%A
    if "%%A"=="System Type:               X86-based PC" (
      net use m: \\%%i\C$ /user:domain\username "password"
      xcopy "C:\batch_file\x86.txt" \\%%i\C$\_support\setup\ /y
      net use m: /delete
    ) else (
      net use m: \\%%i\C$ /user:domain\username "password"
      xcopy "C:\batch_file\x64.txt" \\%%i\C$\_support\setup\ /y
      net use m: /delete
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: I ran the above script but it says, The system cannot find the file \\ip_address. I don't understand what's wrong with \\%%i

Comment: @user1712002 - The DO clause was missing the leading single quote. All fixed now.

Comment: Yes, I found it. One more correction was the lower case l for %Logs%. Thank you so much for your help. It works!

Comment: @user1712002 - The upper case `L` came from your original code. The case of variable names does not matter. I'm glad it works. If the answer meets your needs, you should accept it by clicking on the check-mark near the upper left corner of the answer. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 rep points for taking the time to accept an answer, and awards the answer poster 15 points. Only one answer can be accepted.

Comment: My apologize! I didn't notice that! I accepted as you said! Once again, thanks for your help.